# flash click and drag sametime doesnt work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop

I have a seek bar for video player
just like youtube, user can drag the cursor in seekbar or click anywhere on seekbar to jump to the time
I use mouse.down and mouse_up event for dragging the cursor:

```
mc.cursor.addEventListener(mouse_down)=>mc.cursor.startdrag(); 
mc.cursor.addEventListener(mouse_up)=>mc.cursor.stopdrag();
```

and for clicking:

```
mc.addEventLister(mouseevent.click)=>mouseEvent.target.mouseX
```

here is my problem:
if I do only clicking or dragging nothing wrong
but when I do both clicking works but dragging isnt
when mc.cursor.mouseEvent up is called mc.mouseEvent click is also called and since `mc.cursor` is clicked click event got the coordinates wrong
I remove the click event in mouseEvent up function in 1st line and in the last line I add again but it does the samething again

how can I use them in the sametime
thanks

Comment: bad practice to put mouse event in child and parent only the parent event will be fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best way to go here would be to attach the click handler to the bar (you have an horizontal bar BELOW the cursor, right?).

So, it would go something like this:

```
var timelineBar:Sprite = mc.bar; // This is the clickable horizontal bar below the cursor
var cursor:Sprite = mc.cursor; // This is your current cursor

// Add dragging events to the cursor sprite
cursor.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN); // start drag 
cursor.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP); // stop drag 

// Add the CLICK event to the timeline-bar Sprite INSTEAD of to the cursor's parent
timelineBar.addEventLister( MouseEvent.CLICK );
```

Comment: thanks I was using like timelineBar.cursor.addEvent..... when I seperate cursor from timelineBar it works